# Workflow missing from explanation panel of access viewer

Tags: security, workflow

Does anyone know what triggers the workflow section to appear in the explanation panel of access viewer. I have the same user account configured with the same permissions on both UAT and Production. When viewing permissions on UAT I see the workflow section, but on Production I don't. Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In the Sitecore `Access Viewer` ribbon there is `Columns` button.

Click on it and check both `Workflow State Delete` and `Workflow State Write` checkboxes.

Select again access rights you want to see:

[image]

Comment: Great thanks, I'd done that but still weren't seeing the workflow permissions in the side panel. However I've just checked again and it's visible now, guess it just needed a browser restart.